# What is precedence in this expression?

Tags: perl, perlop

When I run this program:

```
print(rand*100)
```

I get values from `[0,1)` range.

But for this:

```
print(100*rand)
```

I get values from `[0,100)` range.

What is precedence here? and why first expression does not return values from `[0,100)` range?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`rand` has two syntax:

- `rand`
- `rand EXPR`

If what follows `rand` can be the start of an expression (`EXPR`), Perl assumes you are using the latter form.

`*` can start an `EXPR`, so `rand*...` is parsed as `rand EXPR`. This means that `rand*100` is equivalent to `rand(*100)`.

```
$ perl -MO=Deparse,-p -wle'print(rand*100)'
BEGIN { $^W = 1; }
BEGIN { $/ = "\n"; $\ = "\n"; }
print(rand(*100));
-e syntax OK

$ perl -wle'print(rand*100)'
Argument "*main::100" isn't numeric in rand at -e line 1.
0.57355563536203
```

Comment: Two things that make this ambiguity even more fun: Spaces between sigils and variable names are allowed, so `rand * 100` still does not avoid this issue; and it happens with `rand / 100` too just resulting in a parse error once the parser realizes there's no closing `/`.

Answer (score 2):

You can always use [B::Deparse](https://metacpan.org/pod/B::Deparse) to see how Perl is parsing an expression.

```
$ perl -MO=Deparse -e'print(100*rand)'
print 100 * (rand);
-e syntax OK
$ perl -MO=Deparse -e'print(rand*100)'
print rand *100;
-e syntax OK
```

Comment: What an honour ... I've actually got your "Data Munging with Perl" on my bookshelf directly above me. Metaphoric in more ways than one ;-)